# How to generate sequences in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below. I want to generate sequences for each FlagA, FlagB and FlagC columns which aggregates the flags in that day and earlier 4 days. So, it should start from the 5th row, and generate a 'UUDUD', 'UDUDU', 'DUDUU'... flags for FlagA column.

First, I tried to loop in dataframe, but as I read it is not an appropriate way to iterate in a data frame. What is the proper way to do that?

```
                           open_price_change  open_close_gap  volume_change FlagA  FlagB FlagC
2002-01-03 00:00:00+00:00           0.042522        0.023910       0.204788   U     U     U
2002-01-04 00:00:00+00:00           0.014768        0.015246      -0.324674   U     U     D
2002-01-05 00:00:00+00:00           0.042522        0.023910       0.204788   D     U     U
2002-01-06 00:00:00+00:00           0.014768        0.015246      -0.324674   U     D     D
2002-01-07 00:00:00+00:00           0.014768        0.015246      -0.324674   D     U     D
2002-01-08 00:00:00+00:00           0.042522        0.023910       0.204788   U     U     U
2002-01-09 00:00:00+00:00           0.014768        0.015246      -0.324674   U     D     D
2002-01-10 00:00:00+00:00           0.014768        0.015246      -0.324674   D     U     U
2002-01-11 00:00:00+00:00           0.014768        0.015246      -0.324674   U     U     D
2002-01-12 00:00:00+00:00           0.042522        0.023910       0.204788   U     U     U
2002-01-13 00:00:00+00:00           0.014768        0.015246      -0.324674   U     U     D
```

Comment: read up on the `rolling` method of DataFrames

Comment: thanks, it is the thing what I am looking for. It is very easy to sum 5 days values as moving, but I can't find the function to aggregate strings.

Comment: @PaulH, if there's a solution to this using `rolling`, I'd be excited to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to do this using column operations, but there's nothing wrong with looping through the values in the column for something like this:

```
FlagA = df['FlagA'].tolist()
FlagA_sequence = ["".join(FlagA[i:i+5]) for i in range(5,len(x)-5)]
```

if you're looking to make it a columns in the dataframe, you can either do:

```
df['FlagA_sequence']=[np.nan]*5 + ["".join(FlagA[i:i+5]) for i in range(5,len(x)-5)]
```

or use `.shift()` for a more pandas-oriented solution:

```
df['FlagA_sequence']= pd.concat([df['FlagA'].shift(i) for i in range(5)], axis=1).dropna(how='any').sum(1)
```

Comment: The last one is best fit for me.  observation_data['open_price_obsrv_sequence'] = pd.concat([observation_data['open_price_obsrv'].shift(i) for i in range(5)], axis = 1).sum(1).astype(str).sum(1).str.replace("nan","") I did this, but getting an error such as No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Yes, if you want it as a new column in the dataframe, that's the most robust solution. Note that if you've got any missing data, it'll create a window of 5 missing values.